# How to ignore bad avro files while reading from a folder into RDD

Tags: pyspark

I'm reading a set of avro files from a folders and the program error out with the error message.
//Formatting is not properly done.

```
df =sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/data/hadoop20180516/22/abc*.avro").count()
[Stage 2:==================================================>(27818 + 4) / 28318]18/06/14 10:53:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 27900.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 27905)
```

java.io.IOException: Not an Avro data file

Folder has 30K+ files and one of the file might be corrupt.
I would like to ignore the bad file and continue to load rest of the file.s

I tried to use .option command
.option("badRecordsPath", "/tmp/badRecordsPath") and it didn't work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python enough to give you a good code sample, but I solved this in Scala, so you can try:

Read all the files inside the folder using

```
val paths = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(folderPath).collect { case x: (String, String) => x._1 }.collect()
```

Here I use a partial function to get only the keys (file paths), and collect again to iterate through an array of strings, not RDD of strings

Load each file as a DataFrame and skip the ones that fail

```
val filteredDFs = files.map { path =>
      Try(sparkSession
        .read
        .format(format)
        .options(options)
        .load(path)).toOption}.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
```

And finally create a DataFrame containing all previous DFs using union

```
val finalDF = filteredDfs.reduce((df1, df2) => df1.union(df2))
```

Comment: What I understood from the above code is that you are first getting the file path and then using a try block to load the file into a dataframe. if the file is corrupt, it will not load..I'm not sure whether try command is available in pyspark.. let me explore it.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.
And in the map, in python would be something like:
try:
   sparkSession.read.format(format).options(options).load(path)
except: 
  someOtherType
And then try to filter out the someOtherType, so in the end you will have a collection of DataFrames, and you do the union on them.