# Read only parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to read multiple parquet files from a folder which also contains some other file types(csv,avro) into a dataframe. I want to read only if its parquet and skip and go to next if any other.
The problem is parquet file might not have extension and codec might also vary from file to file. In Spark-scala is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried spark.read.parquet(path to file)? What did it do? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Even if you use `spark.read.parquet(path)`, it will give you an exception when in encounters any other file type. The best way is to try to modify the flow to make sure every file has an extension, and iterate through the files and use `filter` to only read parquet files.
If you can't do that, do the same, iterate through the files and use try-catch to skip the ones that give an exception, like in my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51042091/3000244

Comment: Not sure what exactly you looking for, but you can try this `spark.read.parquet("/foldername/*/*/*.parquet")` here `* and *` replaced by nested folder if you have more than two nested folder then add another `*` like this `/*/*/*/*.parquet`

Comment: Giving extension is not possible in my case, even after handling exception program fails at line where trying to read parquet file when any other type encountered java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file:

Comment: So in this case you should iterate all path check those file which ends with (.endsWith("parquet")) parquet and add those path in one list/array/set's then used spark read. for ex. if list path having all path with parquet file then used this code `val path=List("path1","path2",....,"pathn"); spark.read.parquet(path:_*)`

Comment: So what about parquet file which does not have extension as .parquet

Comment: those file consider as text file, for parquet file always have extension .parquet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filenames beforehand in the following way:

```
improt org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import scala.sys.process._

val fileNames: List[String] = "hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/files/on/hdfs".!!
                             .split("\n")
                             .filter(_.endsWith(".parquet"))
                             .map(_.split("\\s").last).toList

val df: DataFrame = spark.read.parquet(fileNames:_*)
```

`spark` in the above code is the `SparkSession` object. This code should work for Spark 1.x versions as well since the method signature for `parquet()` is the same in Spark 1.x and Spark 2.x versions.

Comment: Hi Yayati, 
1. Files which needs to be processed don't have extension. They are part_** files created from some other code.
2. There are various type of files coming as input such as parquet, avro . The type needs to be determined in the code and some custom function according to each file type need to be performed.

Comment: @Prachi I don;t think there is a way to do what you propose.  One way would be to create subdirectories for separate file-types and read the appropriate directories. This would save time, and you won't have to write code to insepect the **part_** files to identify their types